# convert normal html string to Valid w3 standard

Tags: php, preg-replace

i want to create convert normal codes(html) to standard code (by w3 http://validator.w3.org/)

Even if you are not 100% valid;

what is best pattern for this work ?

```
function besterCode($htmlString){
    $FINAL_OUT = $htmlString;
    $FINAL_OUT = str_replace('" >','">',$FINAL_OUT) ;
    $FINAL_OUT = str_replace('" >','">',$FINAL_OUT) ;

    preg_replace(......)// what is best pattern >

    return $FINAL_OUT;
}

?>
```

Comment: I dont understand the questions, do you mean convert to HTML entities, something like this --- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: i want get standard code (input:html output:html)

Comment: Use something like `['"]\s*>` and replace it with `">`

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER yes but i want full pattern for any errors in http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Trying to use regex to parse invalid HTML is insane, and writing software to try to fix up broken HTML is (a) a *huge* project (far, far too broad for a stackoverflow question) and (b) depends on a lot of guesswork

Comment: For example, how should the error "div element not allowed here" be fixed? The two obvious solutions are "move it somewhere else" and "use a different element", but which and where or what? The software can't know what the author was trying to express, the HTML is supposed to tell them that but we know the HTML is wrong.

Comment: @ErfanSafarpoor You can wellform and pretty up your HTML but no restructer it along the W3C validator rules automatically with just a piece of regex.

Comment: for sample i want replace all title attr of img tags to alt ! this is not hard !

Comment: @ErfanSafarpoor — Describing one (relatively simple) fix you want to make (which is probably wrong quite a lot of the time since title and alt are not interchangeable) out of the thousands of fixes you'd need to implement does not mean the problem is "not hard"!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to automatically correct html. You can try using the [`tidy`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.html.php) extension for php

```
$tidy = tidy_parse_string("<a href=''>sfdd");
$html = $tidy->html();
echo $html->value;
```

**Output**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href=''>sfdd</a>
</body>
</html>
```